# Advantages of different data storage types and when to use it?

Tags: javascript, rdbms, data-storage

I am a coding beginner and I need help deciding on the way I will store data for the website I am building. I have a section on my website where I will be listing items. Each item will have several properties. I was thinking between javascript objects or storing the item and the item's properties in a database. What are some situations where I should use a database, js objects, or view files? Any advantages of each type? Also how about when you are trying to sort the items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store data in your database **Only** When you need !

- If you don't have any logic process on this data in your server, there is no need for storing in database, So just store in your View files.
- Also if you don't need this items in your javascript code so  don't store them in js file ! just write them wherever you need.

EDIT :

If you have some operations like sort, order and etc :

- If your data will have many changes and process it's better to store in database.
- If your data will not have many changes and is some constants, so just stroe them in a javascript object.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to tell you that I wanted to make the items to be sorted, so change the order, or hide or show. I'm not sure if you can do that with view files but do you know any other ways?